# Getx setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

im using Getx for my state management so the case is i have a screen with detail of the video and a list tile for another suggested video. in the screen i call initstate to call Getx function to fetch the video detail data like this

the point is what is the proper way to call getx function on screen build is it only with initState? if i use onInit in the controller it only initialize upon the controller build not the screen build

```
// video detail screen
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        videoC.getVideoDetail(videoId: widget.data);
      }
  

// get video detail
  var videoDetailLoading = false.obs;
  var videoDetail = {}.obs;
  getVideoDetail({videoId}) {
    videoDetail.clear();
    videoDetailLoading.value = true;
    String endpoint = 'video/$videoId';

    http.get(endpoint).then(
      (res) {
        log('$endpoint item === $res');

        if (res['status']) {
          videoDetail.value = res['data'];
          videoDetail.refresh();
        } else {}

        videoDetailLoading.value = false;
      },
    ).catchError((onError) {
      videoDetailLoading.value = false;
      // Get.back();
      // Helper().snakbar(isSuccess: false, message: 'Layar tidak tersedia');
      log('$endpoint onError === $onError');
    });
  }
```

but after i navigate to the detail screen by tapping the suggested video

[image]

(basically it just navigate to the same screen but different data) then it throws this error

[image]

```
This Obx widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: Obx
    has builder
    state: _ObxState#45cea
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: Builder
The relevant error-causing widget was
GetMaterialApp
lib/main.dart:16
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
```

what is the proper way to call getx function on screen build is it only with initState? if i use onInit in the controller it only initialize upon the controller build not the screen build

Comment: You need to provide more Widget code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screen is refreshing before it's not loaded fully so getting this error, Please try with below code.

```
video detail screen
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallBack((timeStamp){
    videoC.getVideoDetail(videoId: widget.data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: what is this WidgetBinding ?

Comment: The code is incorrect. It is: WidgetsBinding.instance.AddPostFrameCallback